# locate stop repeating when a directory contains a name

Tags: locate

Sometimes when using locate, my search string will (either incidentally or intentionally) match a portion of a directory. This causes everything below that point in the directory to be printed. For example:

```
$ locate lib
/home/myname/libImWorkingOn/libImWorkingOn.so
/lib/
/lib/modules/
/lib/firmware/
.... etc
```

This quickly gets out of hand and makes it difficult to search.

Is there a way to prevent this? For example, have it print:

```
$locate lib
/home/myname/libImWorkingOn/libImWorkingOn.so
/lib/
```

And nothing more?

Additionally, is it possible to look for a directory and have locate pick up just the directories?

For example (looking for qemu base folder)

Actual:

```
$locate qemu
home/myname/qemu
home/myname/qemu/.svn
home/myname/qemu/.svn/.....
home/myname/qemu/Makefile
.....
usr/bin/qemu
.....
```

Desired:

```
$locate (option) qemu
/home/myname/qemu
/usr/bin/qemu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On systems with the `mlocate` version of `locate`, you could limit the matches using the `-b` or `--basename` option:

```
locate -b lib
```

... which would limit the results to files whose names contain the string. On my system, this results in many fewer matches:

```
$ locate lib | wc -l
28901
$ locate -b lib | wc -l
3430
```

Comment: This definitely improves the results, but it doesn't cover the use case of looking for a directory. Is there a way to do that as well?

Answer (score 2):

**`locate`** prints a list of absolute pathnames.  You can *always* pipe the result through **`grep`** to obtain just filenames

```
locate lib |grep -E '/lib$'
```

or just directory names

```
locate lib |grep '/lib/' | sed -e 's,/lib/.*$,/lib,' | sort -u
```

If you did this frequently enough, you could write a small script that did each of those (parameterizing the "lib", of course).

Answer (score 0):

we can limit the number of entries by using `-l` option as below.

```
 locate -w lib -l 1
```

- `-w` match the exact word
- `-l` Exit successfully after finding number occurrence  which specified

Or you can use `-b` option

```
locate -b '\lib' -l 1
```

- `-b` Match only the base name against the specified patterns